# 4.6.2 on Joomla: Entering Contribution under single contact times out

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, contributions, 4.6.2

What log information is best to post for this issue?
When I manually enter a contribution under the Contribution tab of a contact's record, the process times out with a blank white screen. When I enter it as a "New Contribution" under the Contributions menu item, it works flawlessly.

I did test this in the Demo Joomla and it does work. My database has over 30k contacts.

I am not knowledgeable of the process flow so I am probably wrong about this but could the problem be a contact_id search issue since with a "New Contribution" a search of the contact is required/retrieved first rather than the process having to go out and search for the contact under the in-record process?

Answer (score 1):

To debug a PHP timeout issue, locate your PHP error log and check the last line or last few lines.

This should reveal what code is exhausting your allocated time - and also the time you're hosting environment allows.

Add that information to your question and the community may be able to better identify the underlying issue.